# Get path to which a command's output has been redirected

Tags: linux

Is there a way to find what path a command has had it's output redirected to (if it has been)?

I tried using:

```
ps -p PID -o cmd
```

Thinking I could look for a `>` and extract the path from that, but the output doesn't have that part in it.  I'm pretty sure it hasn't just been truncated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the proc file system `/proc/self/fd` for this

```
readlink /proc/self/fd/1
```

for stdout or `2` for stderr.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the PID, just inspect `/proc/ID/fd/1`. It should be linked to the actual path:

```
$ watch date > /tmp/1 &
[1] 27346
$ ls -l /proc/27346/fd/1
l-wx------ 1 choroba users 64 2013-02-15 16:28 /proc/27346/fd/1 -> /tmp/1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `lsof` (list open files) command to see what files a process has open for writing.

For example:

```
$ lsof -p 31714
COMMAND   PID  USER      FD   TYPE DEVICE    SIZE       NODE NAME
bash    31714 dogbane    0u   CHR  136,4                  6 /dev/pts/4
bash    31714 dogbane    1w   REG    8,1      15    2032202 /tmp/t
```

The `w` in the FD (file descriptor) column means that `/tmp/t` is open for writing.

Answer (score 0):

How about it?

```
[root@us04 ~]# ls -l /proc/14170/exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Feb 15 10:36 /proc/14170/exe -> /usr/sbin/httpd
```

One more example:

```
[root@us04 ~]# readlink -f /proc/5352/exe
/sbin/syslogd
```